# Javascript. Ошибка при подключении библиотеки Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babel

Помогите разобраться с подключением библиотеки.
Установил слeдующую библиотеку - node-gost (https://github.com/romansopov/crypto)

Пытаюсь подключить ее в свой проект так:

```
const gost = require("../../node_modules/node-gost/index");
```

и так

```
import * as gost from "../../node_modules/node-gost/index";
```

Получаю ошибку: Module not found: Can't resolve 'gostRandom' in '/home/user/project/node_modules/node-gost/lib'.

Содержимое index.js библиотеки:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/gostCrypto');
require('./lib/gostASN1');
require('./lib/gostCert');
require('./lib/gostCipher');
require('./lib/gostCMS');
require('./lib/gostCoding');
require('./lib/gostDigest');
require('./lib/gostEngine');
require('./lib/gostKeys');
require('./lib/gostRandom');
require('./lib/gostSecurity');
require('./lib/gostSign');
require('./lib/gostViewer');
```

В библеотеке есть тестовый файл test.js, в котором подключение работает корректно.

```
const gost = require('./index');
console.log(gost);
```

Comment: `require("node-gost");` пробовали?

Comment: @Darth, да. Подключая, как const gost = require("node-gost"), получаю ту же ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

проверил на npm 5.5.1 + node9.2.0  работает.

Package.json

```
{
 "name": "gost-test",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
    "node-gost": "^1.0.0"
 }
}
```

index.js

```
const gost = require('node-gost')
console.log(gost)
```

Terminal:

```
node .\index.js
{ subtle: SubtleCrypto {},
  getRandomValues: [Function],
  coding: GostCoding {},
  security: {},
  asn1: {},
  cert: GostCert {},
  cms: GostCMS {},
  keys: GostKeys {} }
```

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я ее ставил из npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gost

Comment: хмм  npmjs поиск не нашел ее. Вы правы она там есть. Я только что проверил и все работает. Какая версия nodejs у Вас? моя npm 5.5.1 node v9.2.0.

Comment: npm 3.10.8, node v6.9.1
Не думаю, что дело в версии. Все таки файл test.js  из библиотеки запускается и работает как надо. Проблема - подключить эту библиотеку в проект.

Comment: Другие библиотеки подключаются без проблем? Через require() ?

Comment: Честно говоря, до этого момента использовал подключения толкьо через import, как import {push} from "react-router-redux";
Через require() сейчас попробовал подключить другие библиотеки - не работает.

Comment: интересно! Вы пользуетесь Babel ?

Comment: Проект создавал при помощи create-react-app. Babel, насколько мне известно, уже включен в него и настроен.